# Leap Motion: rotationAxis – shouldn't it be around 0 if hand is held still

Tags: javascript, rotation, axis, leap-motion

I am trying to build something like a rotary know gesture with leap motion.
Therefore I'm trying out some of the methods of LeapJS.
In this case the hand.rotationAxis() method
[LeapJS rotationAxis](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/javascript/api/Leap.Hand.html#Hand.rotationAxis)

In the description it says:
The axis of rotation derived from the change in orientation of this hand, and associated fingers, **between the current frame and the specified frame.**

If I use the given code sample with the comparison between the current and the previous frame. I still get clear rotation values. Although I was expecting that if I hold my hand still, the values would be around 0 (because of no change).

```
[Log] Axis of Rotation: (0.4760923683643341, -0.8311813473701477, 0.2871823012828827)
[Log] Axis of Rotation: (0.47683998942375183, -0.8305783271789551, 0.28768599033355713)
[Log] Axis of Rotation: (0.4789084196090698, -0.8291669487953186, 0.2883208692073822)
[Log] Axis of Rotation: (0.48095035552978516, -0.8275532126426697, 0.2895556390285492)
[Log] Axis of Rotation: (0.48164039850234985, -0.8270854949951172, 0.28974488377571106)
[Log] Axis of Rotation: (0.4823167622089386, -0.8265553116798401, 0.29013246297836304)
[Log] Axis of Rotation: (0.48576226830482483, -0.8241119384765625, 0.29133230447769165)
[Log] Axis of Rotation: (0.4900607168674469, -0.8206855654716492, 0.2937954068183899)
```

In this example I held my hand still. You can see that the values don't change much, but as I said, I would have expected them to be around 0 because it should be comparing to the previous frame.

Can somebody enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

I obviously misunderstood the description a bit. The rotation Axis is a direction vector and its length is = 1. (only exception would be 0, and that means the rotation would be exactly 0, which is very unlikely).
In comparison the rotationAngle property is close to 0, but not the axis.